# ¿Por qué se usa el subjuntivo en «una simple casualidad que revelara...»?

Tags: subjuntivo

De *Cien años de solidad*:

> Así que fue una simple casualidad que **revelara** sus sentimientos
>   políticos, y fue un puro golpe de curiosidad el que lo **metió** en la
>   ventolera de visitar al médico para tratarse un dolor que no tenía.

Además, ¿por qué se usa la forma verbal de «meter» en indicativo?

Comment: metió no es indicativo, es pretérito acompañado del Complemento directo "lo" , probablemente utilizando "el" en lugar de "lo" para evitar cacofonía.  por que... se utilizan asi ? creo que es un llamado para @Guifa !

Comment: @Mike metió sí es indicativo, modo indicativo. Quizá lo has confundido con "infinitivo", a mí también me ha pasado.

Comment: «Metió» es modo indicativo (sin duda), pero es tiempo verbal pretérito perfecto simple, mejor conocido como pretérito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las reglas del subjuntivo son un poco opacas, dada su historia como la fusión de [dos modos históricos indoeuropeos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subjunctive_mood#Indo-European_languages) (más o menos "tal vez sea" y "así sea") y su evolución continual hasta el latín y el castellano.

No obstante, este artículo clasifica las distintas situaciones en las cuales el subjuntivo se usaría cuando se habla de *hechos*. En la sección relevante (23, 24), se explica que cuando se habla de algo:

1. que ha pasado por casualidad/suerte/azar
2. y que también es extraño o requiere explicación

se invoca el subjuntivo:

> **4.** Two types of clause that are indicative in most languages are now subjunctive in Spanish, when they occur in very specific situations that will be defined below...
>
> *Affective* clauses name what is out of the ordinary or strange in the context, what may call for explanation or be the subject of comment.
>
> ...
>
> ### **CHANCE**
>
> **23.** What has happened by chance, without assignable cause, in the natural course of events, is expressed in the mood determined by presence or absence of affectivity.
>
> **AFFECTIVE, INFORMATIVE**
>
> **24.** Strange or unexpected, favorable or unfavorable.
>
> > Acaeció, desgraciadamente, que hubiera en el grupo un miembro de la oposición. Así sucedió que toda la Canaria se poblase. Llegó el caso de que los ciudadanos trabasen altercados con las tropas. Dió el caso de que tumbados en medio del camino, se negaran a seguir. Fue Dios servido que a la hora de mediodía sobresaltase a Su Majestad el mismo accidente de fiebre maligno. Realmente **fué una casualidad** que yo me **encontrara** en el auditorio en aquella histórica ocasión. En un estanque se ha dado el caso de que mate a un pez sesenta veces más pesado que él.
>
> - [*Subjunctive of Fact*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/337017), Gordon T. Fish (*Hispania* Vol. 46, No.2) (1963)

Answer (score 1):

That is a very good question.

The only explanation I can think of is:

1) "Revelara" is subjunctive because it is kind of equivalent to

```
"El hecho de que eso pudiera ocurrir" fue una casualidad.
```

So it's true it happened, so it should be a fact, but you are talking about the **idea**, and ideas are not exactly facts.

2) This one has puzzled me a little bit. I'd use subjunctive here too, because of the same reason.

However, in both cases you can use any of them.

Subjunctive is more abstract, it refers to the idea.
Indicative mood highlights that it actually happened.

Comment: ¿y yo por qué lo he escrito en inglés si la pregunta estaba en español? jaja. Creo que es el modo automático. Si quieres, la traduzco.